# Testing on Heteroscedasticity with White Test

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have already tested for heteroskedasticity with the Breusch-Pagan Test and found that the test came out positive.

Based on the template that I have from a book, one should now also check with the White test whether heteroskedasticity is present.

Unfortunately, the test does not want to work for me:/

This is how my calculation looks like:

```
install.packages(c("AER"))
library(AER)


bptest(r1, varformula = ~ log(intr) + log(sale_py_at_py) + log(R_at_py) 
       + log(p_con) + log(txt) + factor(Dummy_SIC)
       + I(log(intr))^2 + I(log(sale_py_at_py))^2 + I(log(R_at_py))^2 
        + I(log(p_con))^2 + I(log(txt))^2 + I(factor(Dummy_SIC))^2
        + I(log(intr)*log(sale_ap_at_py)) + I(log(intr)*log(R_at_py))
        + I(log(intr)*log(p_con)) + I(log(intr)*log(txt)) 
        + I(log(sale_ap_at_py)*loglog(R_at_py)) 
        + I(log(sale_ap_at_py)*loglog(p_con))
         + I(log(sale_ap_at_py)*loglog(txt))
         + I(log(R_at_py)*loglog(p_con)) + I(log(R_at_py)*loglog(txt))
         + I(log(p_con)*loglog(txt)) + I(log(intr)*factor(Dummy_SIC))
         + I(log(sale_py_at_py)*factor(Dummy_SIC))
         + I(log(R_at_py)*factor(Dummy_SIC)) 
         + I(log(p_con)*factor(Dummy_SIC)) 
          + I(log(txt)*factor(Dummy_SIC)), data = r1)
```

This is the error:

> error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component
> nor attribute") :  no terms component nor attribute

**Where is my error in the calculation or what do I have to do differently?**

Explanation of variables:

marketingspending= marketing spending, intr= interest rate, sale_py_at_py= sale(t-1)/asset(t-1), R_at_py= 1/asset(t-1), txt= tax, p_con= consumption(t-1), DummySIC means that I divided them into 8 groups of segments (sic) the company is working in (Group 0-7). And if the company is in the Group 1 it gets a 1 for DummySIC1 and 0 in every other Dummy-group (and so on for every group).

My original regression looks like this:

```
lm.01.1 <-lm(marketingspending ~ intr + sale_py_at_py + R_at_py + txt 
           + dt + factor(Dummy_SIC), data=Relevante_V03)
```

Afterwards I had to make changes so that the conditions of a regression are fulfilled (checked by `gvlma()`). For this, I deleted extreme values and took `log()`. So the regression
looks like this:

```
lm.01.3 <-lm(log(marketingspending) ~ log(intr) + log(sale_py_at_py) 
             + log(R_at_py) + log(p_con) + log(txt) + factor(Dummy_SIC)
             , data=r1)
```

Edit 1:

I applied the suggestions of the comments so the function looks now like this:

```
 bptest(lm.01.3, varformula = ~ log(intr) + log(sale_py_at_py) + log(R_at_py) 
       + log(p_con) + log(txt) + factor(Dummy_SIC)
       + I(log(intr))^2 + I(log(sale_py_at_py))^2 + I(log(R_at_py))^2 
        + I(log(p_con))^2 + I(log(txt))^2 + I(factor(Dummy_SIC))^2
        + I(log(intr)*log(sale_py_at_py)) + I(log(intr)*log(R_at_py))
        + I(log(intr)*log(p_con)) + I(log(intr)*log(txt)) 
        + I(log(sale_py_at_py)*log(R_at_py)) 
        + I(log(sale_py_at_py)*log(p_con))
         + I(log(sale_py_at_py)*log(txt))
         + I(log(R_at_py)*log(p_con)) + I(log(R_at_py)*log(txt))
         + I(log(p_con)*log(txt)) + I(log(intr)*factor(Dummy_SIC))
         + I(log(sale_py_at_py)*factor(Dummy_SIC))
         + I(log(R_at_py)*factor(Dummy_SIC)) 
         + I(log(p_con)*factor(Dummy_SIC)) 
          + I(log(txt)*factor(Dummy_SIC)), data = r1)
```

Now I get the following error:

> Error in lm.fit(X, y) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Does that mean I can't use the white test because of the factor variable?

Extra information:

I am doing a regression to test the influences on marketing spending.

Comment: Oh okay sorry... I added it :/

Comment: The first argument to `bptest` is the formula. The error occurs because there were problems interpreting `r1` as a formula. You have given it the same object as you are giving to the data argument. To say anything further we would need to see output of `str(r1)`

Comment: Also I see no `loglog` function in pkg:AER and I know for a fact it's not a base function.

Comment: @IRTFM The first argument can be a formula, or a fitted model object. I believe the arguments are correct for a White test - it's the formatting of the `varFormula` that is wrong.

Comment: I cannot parse your last comment into standard English. (You might also go back and put in a few checkmarks for the earlier answered questions you have posted in the last 6 weeks.)

Comment: @IRFTM So I insert the variable to be explained at the place where currently r1 is (directly at the beginning)

Comment: @IRTFM if the question had been answered, I would, but as here in this question I get only some suggestions that unfortunately do not lead to a result or do not help me for my question (but may help others for simpler approaches). Apart from that, I don't know exactly what I did to you that you write me so unkindly.

Comment: I don’t think pointing out errors or omissions on a coding Q&A venue is unkind. As far as asking you to review your activity it stems from seeing a Q where you complimented the A and there was no checkmark and then seeing that you had a significant number of unchecked questions. Admittedly the sampling was inadequate. All I asked was that you review you postings.

Comment: As far as the structure of the arguments in your amended question goes, it seems very unlikely that ‘log(marketspending)’ is an R formula. What is ‘str(r1)’? And can you express the statistical question fully?

Comment: Ah okay you meant that I should use the regression itself in the beginning and I also added the statistical question for the regression

Comment: Do you have negative values? The following snippet will give a similar error: `lm(1~log(-1))`